# How do I change shells (bash to ksh) on OS 10.9.1?

Tags: macos, command-line

I need to brush up on ksh after an 8 year hiatus.  How can I run korn shell in my OS 10.9.1 terminal then switch back to bash when done with tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to just start Terminal as usual and type `ksh` to start a Korn shell. If you want to open a new Terminal window for it, type <kbd>Shift-Cmd-N</kbd> and run `ksh` from there.

Depending on how your `.profile` looks like, you might need to change it as well to identify the shell it's running under and execute initialization commands accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the shell that is used for new Terminal windows, run `chsh -s /bin/ksh` to change the default login shell, or change the command that shells open with from Terminal's preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your users and group settings, control-click on your account for advanced options:

[image]